# Atom.io's fonts broken after update to 18.04

Tags: gui, 18.04, atom

Just upgraded to 18.4 and while the system seems fine, atom.io's letters seem in disarray as if there is a problem with the fonts. Any idea how to fix this without a complete re-install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall does not have to be "complete" - just reinstall only `atom` - it helped in my case and all looks good on atom 1.26.1

Comment: I did that at the end, the result was that Atom was freezing on opening. at the end I removed ~/.atom as well (and copied over some stuff)... Thanks in any case.